# Modular Programming and Structured Programming

Tags: asp.net, module, modularity, modular

I was asked to design a asp.net website with modular programming, yet I have no clue what that actually means, does he mean structured programming?, everything Ive found on modular programming has no relation to an asp.net website (or its code behind).

Could some one explain what it means if:

I have a database connection on each page of the website rather than having the connection string in the global or webconfig page? Does this mean structured or oop or modular?

In what terms could you achieve modular programming with a website that has no loadable modules? Its just a site with a few connection strings and some clever programming to do some fancy html?

Ive seen other posts about webparts and cms but really have no understanding of them? Are they relevant? Unsure.

My site is just a social network site that allows some one to login/create account with the website then go to his own profile and display things about himself that are saved to our database.

Nothing in it requires modules as far as I can tell?

So it makes me think is it a different method of actually "programming" writing the code? i.e is it stored in a different manner is it refrenced in a different manner is called in a different manner?

Comment: Does the person who asked you to do this know anything about programming?

Comment: haha... That question still remains. But if I can get to the basis of what he is meaning or trying to mean it will solve my lack of understanding

Comment: I think you'll be better off just asking that person what he wants. Ask for well-defined requirements, not overly broad, overloaded terms like "modular". Ask things like "What is a module?" "So, would X be a module?" "Give me examples of modules".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this context, you could structure your data access code in its own project and call the web application a module and the data access layer a module.

If the data access layer is complicated with a good number of entities, you could break that out into several projects (treating each project as a module).

Comment: So your saying break the code up and right my own dlls for refrence? or web-parts?

Comment: Yes, one way to do it to separate data access / business rules into one or more dlls.  Another good way to approach web projects is to utilize UserControls to wrap up functionality.

Comment: is there a point to it for such a small website? what benefits comes from it apart from complicating the workload? I mean apart from expansion, i see no other benefit when i can call my connection string from the web.config file? and point any future programmer to that connection string, I could also call any database query’s the same way? the only benefit i can see is having an interchangeable way determining the connection strings and its constituent parts?(the query’s) is this what is meant by modular programming and if so is it common to asp.net website construction?

Comment: If im being honest i have never came across it before, was never taught it and really dont know why it has its own category.

Answer (score 1):

I think what's being asked of you is to code the site in such a way that it can easily extended and maintained.

Answer (score 0):

"Modular programming" means that you write an application which is build from independent modules. It doesn't matter what kind of application you have. Just break it on several logical independent parts and they'll become modules.

Comment: application being the keyword im desiging a website there is no applications

Comment: Ok, you may call it web-application.

Comment: unless you want to call the login page an "application" how can I further break up the login page code? it wouldnt make sense why would I need to?

Comment: then it wouldnt be modular it would be webparts like I mentioned? So the question still remains can you achieve modular programming with asp?

Comment: in my context that is (simple website)

Comment: You might want to have modules for the types of content to display like photo galleries, video galleries, guestbooks/comments, favorites books, music, etc. All of these individual pieces of information could be handled by one module.

Comment: @Garrith, I'm sure that your social network needs a data base. Ergo, you had to write code which handles this data base. It is the first module. Also you need some authorization code. This logic could be stored in the second module. Creating the html-code is a job for the third module, etc... In other words, module in this case is just an abstraction for some independent functional part of your application.

Comment: so what is the module? is it a dll, i.e i make my own refrences within the project? Or is it code side?

Comment: exactly xappymah so its just jargon in context to my own site? Right? or should I fire those connection strings etc into a (module) what ever or however that is achieved?

Comment: @Garrith, the module could be represented even with a single directory called "db" containing several php sources. Or module could be represented with a single source file which provides API for working with something (formatted output for example). The main point is that modules are independent. You can safely change one module with another one if they have the same interface.

Comment: Yeah I mean I could see the point of that for a connection string, i.e atm its used with odbc i could make a module for that but at some point change out that module and use a different connection string like ado.net or something maybe? If thats possible if not why not just store it in the webconfig file or global file?

Comment: Store the connection string where you want. But the logic, which handles this string and DB at all, in fact is separate module.

Comment: exactly so why on earth is it im called forth to do modular programming? It makes no sense in my current web project?

Comment: You can put ALL your code in a single source file. Or you can put your code in different files. Which way do you prefer?

Comment: Erm thats abit abstract, atm my code is stored in each webpages .cs file? (the way i prefer) I couldnt imagine it being all under one source file? Or do you mean the web.config source file?

Comment: I mean, if you just separate you website logic in independent parts - it would be enough.